Use dual processor on GeoServer?
I just add a processor to a server, so it become dual processor, but when I open the GeoServer map only one processor is active.
Does anyone know why it happens?


Not a GeoServer issue, I think.  You'll need to look at java/yor application server; for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734229/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-more-than-1-cpu

I found it, the problem is on the server. its the NUMA setting
